# How we can add additional Step 2 as "Billing address" in SAP spartacus storefront

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

Sap Spartacus OOTB shows Shipping Address | Deliver mode | Payment as checkout steps.
I need guidance on how we can add the Billing Address as Step 2 after the current first Step Shipping Address.

I have gone through extending-checkout documentation page https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/extending-checkout/ and Google but have not found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add respective facade mapping with proper connector-adapter-facade for current step

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).